# Vertical alignment of elements inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to programatically set vertical alignment (middle) of all the elements inside UITableView's prototype cell (UILabel, UIImageView)? I would like to set it to middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through custom cell.